# C# difference between Environment.SpecialFolders and Application folders

Tags: c#, special-folders

What is the difference between the magic paths in these namespaces:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

versus

```
Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
```

And

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

versus

```
Application.CommonAppDataPath
```

etc...

Comment: Which is the ***namespace*** of _`Application`_ ?

Comment: @Kiquenet `System.Windows.Forms` and that's the difference...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData' and 'SpecialFolder.ApplicationData'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709269/difference-between-specialfolder-localapplicationdata-and-specialfolder-appli)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same.  The Application version of them is aware of ClickOnce deployment, adjusting the paths accordingly to keep them isolated.

Comment: Which is the safer or more common choice for the average C# application targeting the average user: `Environment.SpecialFolder` or `Application` ?

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local
Application.LocalUserAppDataPath = C:\Users\username\AppData\Local
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData = C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
Application.CommonAppDataPath = C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
```

Local is only ever stored on the local machine. Roaming is copied to the domain server (when in a domain) and is then loaded back onto other machines in that domain when you log on.

Comment: So they are the same? Why have two references to the same paths? And why is CommonAppDataPath under username?

Comment: @Jake - Because not all windows operating systems mean that these are the same. And future ones are not guaranteed to be the same either. You _do_ want your code to work on multiple systems, right?

Comment: @Jake - Apologies for the delay in explanation, I had an edit ready but my battery died last night. I've now applied that edit, so hopefully that'll explain a little better.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer for anyone in the future who lands on this page, for all special folder related questions see the Microsoft's documentation which lists **all** the folder types:

[Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2)