# Difference between 'SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData' and 'SpecialFolder.ApplicationData'?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, application-settings, appdata

On my system, `%AppData%` leads to `ApplicationData` which is `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming`

But there is also `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local`
And for some more confusion `D:\Users\<USER>\AppData\LocalLow`

```
string local = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string roaming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

My question is, to which of these locations should my application save its data?

Are there guidelines for which of these locations to use? And am I leaving myself open to problems if I choose the wrong location?

Comment: The Roaming folder is most commonly used to store data. I don't know the actual difference.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `Roaming` folder is copied between machines when roaming profiles are enabled (in a domain environment). Use it for application data that you want to share between machines. *But don't store large files in there -- IT departments don't like it when you do that, and it increases the time taken for the user to log in and to log out as the files are copied around.*

The `Local` folder is not copied between machines. Use it for application data that's specific to a machine.

The `LocalLow` folder is used for low-privilege tasks (such as Internet Explorer). You shouldn't need to worry about it.

For files that the user specifically saved, you should put them (by default) in the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Any thoughts on how these folders are used for a Windows 8 user that is logged onto the machine with a Microsoft account?  Is a Windows 8 app just a completely different beast, with its own APIs, etc., and the folders used are different / mediated by an API?  Is a Windows 8 user logged on with a MS account a "roaming user"?

Comment: will the roaming folder also work if the computer isn't in a domain at all?

Answer (score 12):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) the difference is that `LocalApplicationData` stays on the local machine and does not roam... `ApplicationData` does roam for example if the user logs onto the domain from a different computer it will be synced...

The `LocalLow` refers to specific situations likea BHO running in "Protected Mode" of IE...

For a standard application always use `ApplicationData`. Use `LocalApplicationData` for things that should NOT roam with the user...

Answer (score 7):

From MSDN - [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx):

> ApplicationData -  The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.
>   A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network. A roaming user's profile is kept on a server on the network and is loaded onto a system when the user logs on.
>
> LocalApplicationData  The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by the current, non-roaming user.

In short, use `ApplicationData` for roaming profiles, and `LocalApplicationData` for non roaming profiles.

Comment: Nicely summarized through an official doc reference. Should be very helpful for readers.