# Read all text with System.Environment.Username

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read all text and replace certain text in a specific location.  That location needs to have the username.

File path:

```
C:\Users\zmatar\AppData\Roaming\NexJen Systems\My
```

Here is what I have.  I get an error saying it cannot find the location.  What I was going to do is maybe pass it to a label and then add the label into the location? idk

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\System.Environment.UserName\AppData\Roaming\NexJen Systems\My\IsisSettings.isis");
text = text.Replace("172.16.1.24", "172.16.1.23");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\System.Environment.UserName\AppData\Roaming\NexJen Systems\My\IsisSettings.isis", text);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to build your pathname with the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enum to retrieve the current user roaming folder. This removes the hard coding of the `Environment.UserName` in the path of the current user roaming folder. It is not mandatory to have the username as part of a user folder in the default position on local disk [See Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848267.aspx).

```
string basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, @"NexJen Systems\My\IsisSettings.isis");
string text = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
text = text.Replace("172.16.1.24", "172.16.1.23");
File.WriteAllText(fullPath, text);
```

You could find a nice explanation about `Environment.SpecialFolder` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709269/what-is-the-difference-between-specialfolder-localapplicationdata-specialfolder) and also some advices about using this folder.

Comment: Upvoted because profile folder names are not necessarily the same as the username.

Comment: I get unrecognized escape sequence on My and IsisSettings.isis

Comment: fixed it by adding a @ string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, @"NexJen Systems\My\IsisSettings.isis");